How do I print each element in an openai ChatCompletion response as JSON on a separate line?
I'm making a simple call to OpenAI using Python asking about where a baseball game was played.
completion = openai.chat.completions.create(
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages = [
  {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
  {"role": "user", "content": "Who won the world series in 2020?"},
  {"role": "assistant", "content": "The Los Angeles Dodgers won the World Series in 2020."},
  {"role": "user", "content": "Where was it played?"}
  ]
)

print (completion)

The output shows up like this:
ChatCompletion(id='chatcmpl-9UgP85B0gYBjEAiYMcF3Ryt9Y3fdZ', choices=[Choice(finish_reason='stop', index=0, logprobs=None, message=ChatCompletionMessage(content='The 2020 World Series was played at Globe Life Field in Arlington, Texas.', role='assistant', function_call=None, tool_calls=None))], created=1717099870, model='gpt-3.5-turbo-0125', object='chat.completion', system_fingerprint=None, usage=CompletionUsage(completion_tokens=17, prompt_tokens=53, total_tokens=70))

But I'd like it to show up like this:
{
  "choices": [
    {
      "finish_reason": "stop",
      "index": 0,
      "message": {
        "content": "The 2020 World Series was played in Texas at Globe Life Field in Arlington.",
        "role": "assistant"
      },
      "logprobs": null
    }
  ],
  "created": 1677664795,
  "id": "chatcmpl-7QyqpwdfhqwajicIEznoc6Q47XAyW",
  "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo-0613",
  "object": "chat.completion",
  "usage": {
    "completion_tokens": 17,
    "prompt_tokens": 57,
    "total_tokens": 74
  }
}

FWIW, I'm using Python 3.12 and Windows Terminal.

if it is not given like this, then you would need to make the key yourself and assign the values accordingly.

also, there should be a comma at the end of this line "logprobs": null or the json will be invalid.

Use .model_dump_json()
completion = client.chat.completions.create(
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages = [
  {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant"},
  {"role": "user", "content": "Who won the world series in 2020?"},
  {"role": "assistant", "content": "The Los Angeles Dodgers won the World Series in 2020."},
  {"role": "user", "content": "Where was it played?"}
  ]
)

data = completion.model_dump_json()
print(data)

Output:
{"id":"chatcmpl-9VGebGyeosYhcWW19F6f5B6lMFhpl","choices":[{"finish_reason":"stop","index":0,"logprobs":null,"message":{"content":"The World Series in 2020 was played at Globe Life Field in Arlington, Texas.","role":"assistant","function_call":null,"tool_calls":null}}],"created":1717239213,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0125","object":"chat.completion","system_fingerprint":null,"usage":{"completion_tokens":18,"prompt_tokens":52,"total_tokens":70}}

If you need to pretty print, you can just use the ident parameter:
data = completion.model_dump_json(indent=3)
print(data)

Output:
{
   "id": "chatcmpl-9VGphVuZLKh2QuqT9vSAUdWCxoifg",
   "choices": [
      {
         "finish_reason": "stop",
         "index": 0,
         "logprobs": null,
         "message": {
            "content": "The 2020 World Series was played at Globe Life Field in Arlington, Texas, home of the Texas Rangers.",
            "role": "assistant",
            "function_call": null,
            "tool_calls": null
         }
      }
   ],
   "created": 1717239901,
   "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo-0125",
   "object": "chat.completion",
   "system_fingerprint": null,
   "usage": {
      "completion_tokens": 23,
      "prompt_tokens": 52,
      "total_tokens": 75
   }
}

